# syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an error which is shouting at me that appears to be a syntax error?
I am really not sure where I am going wrong?

```
public function upload() {
  // getting all of the post data
  $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
  // setting up rules
  $rules = array('image' => 'required',); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
  // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
  $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    // send back to the page with the input data and errors
    return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
  }
  else {
    // checking file is valid.
    if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
      $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
      $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
      $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
      Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
      // sending back with message
      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
      return Redirect::to('upload');
    }
    else {
      // sending back with error message.
      Session::flash('error', 'uploaded file is not valid');
      return Redirect::to('upload');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which line cause problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a context of class to use access identifiers.

Your code should be:

```
class MyClass {
    public function upload() {
      // getting all of the post data
      $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
      // setting up rules
      $rules = array('image' => 'required',); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
      // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
      $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
        // send back to the page with the input data and errors
        return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
      }
      else {
        // checking file is valid.
        if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
          $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
          $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
          $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
          Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
          // sending back with message
          Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
          return Redirect::to('upload');
        }
        else {
          // sending back with error message.
          Session::flash('error', 'uploaded file is not valid');
          return Redirect::to('upload');
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're not inside a class, just use `function upload()`, not `public function upload()`.

If you're inside a class, the error lies before the code you've provided.